# How can I change DataGridColumn binding for selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Let's say I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to a collection of objects. Those objects have properties `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`. I want the 1st column to display `PropertyA` but when I select a row, I wanted the selected row only to display `PropertyB`. How can I do this?

The object

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string PropertyA { get; set; }
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

The xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjects}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyA}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This displays the value in PropertyA for every row in the datagrid. But When I select a row, I want that row only to change to display PropertyB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**XAML:**

```
   Window x:Class="WpfApplication296.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication296"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyA}" FontSize="24" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateB">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyB}" FontSize="24"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" 
               TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateB}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" 
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding PropertyA}" 
                                    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject {PropertyA = " AAA 101", PropertyB=" BBBBBB 001" },
            new MyObject {PropertyA = " AAA 102", PropertyB=" BBBBBB 002" },
            new MyObject {PropertyA = " AAA 103", PropertyB=" BBBBBB 003" },
            new MyObject {PropertyA = " AAA 104", PropertyB=" BBBBBB 004" },
            new MyObject {PropertyA = " AAA 105", PropertyB=" BBBBBB 005" },
        };
    }
}
```

[image]